# Passing value from TpostgresSql to context variable

Tags: talend

I need to pass value from Tpostgressql to context variable,so that context variable value can be used in other components
The query used in tpostgres is :

```
select max(started_on) started_on from etl_log
```

I have created a context variable `started_on_date` (date datatype)

In the Tjavarow :-

```
context.started_on_date =row1.started_on
```

But it throws

> error created_on variable cannot be resolved or is not a field

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the schema in the tPostrgesqlInput component ? If not, that needs to be done first. Afterward, synchronize the schema of the tJavaRow. You can use the Java row's code generation feature, if appropriate .

Question / if you want to do row-based processing in the same job, there is likely no need to put the started date in the context.

If you want to do non-row based processing, you can used the tJavaRow component to put the value in the globalMap. This assumes there is only one row of data or that you only care about the last row. Then, you can use that value in other components which are not processing a flow (rows). tJava is an example of that.